# Execute two statements with a small difference between them

Tags: bash

I often run these statements:

```
docker stop $(docker ps -aq); docker rm $(docker ps -aq)
```

What's the shortest way to type this? I tried

```
docker {stop, rm} $(docker ps -aq)
```

but that doesn't expand to two separate statements.

Comment: Define an alias or a function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The shortest way to is to create a function that runs both commands, put that in your shell's startup files and then use that.

e.g.

```
dstoprm() {
    docker stop $(docker ps -aq)
    docker rm $(docker ps -aq)
}
```

(Even shorter if you make the function have a one-letter name.)

---

To reduce repetition at the cost of boilerplate, you could use a loop:

```
for action in stop rm; do docker $action $(docker ps -aq); done
```

or to create multiple commands with brace expansion, you could do something like this, *not that I'm seriously suggesting anyone to use this*:

```
eval 'docker '{stop,rm}' $(docker ps -aq);'
```

Comment: Or create a small script to do the same thing and put it in ~/bin (and add ~/bin to your PATH if necessary).  Creating lots of functions in your .bashrc or .bash_profile startup files is like caching your personal ~/bin directory's contents in memory every time you login.

Comment: @jrw32982, that function is what, less than a hundred bytes? Even if it takes 20 times that in memory, it's still negligible compared to the size of Bash itself. Running the function from memory is also more efficient than launching another shell to run it as an external script. But yes, it'll work as a script too, sure.

Answer (score 8):

Starting with:

```
docker stop $(docker ps -aq); docker rm $(docker ps -aq)
```

what if we capture the `docker ps -aq` into a variable, so as not to calculate it twice? It's expected to be the same value: all containers. If that were to change, we would be running `rm` on a different set of containers from the ones on which we invoked `stop`:

```
d=$(docker ps -aq); docker stop $d; docker rm $d
```

We have achieved shortening the command sequence and ensuring it operates on the same set of containers.

Comment: This won't work properly if any container names contain whitespace.

Comment: Of course, neither would the OP's original commands, so this is no worse.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, and simply quoting the expansion is a nonstarter. We have to read the names from the standard output of `docker ps` line by line. And then that won't work if they contain newlines; we need to patch `docker ps` to have a `-0` option for null terminated output ...  or we could just not do things like put spaces in programming and system construction/administration artifacts that are not end-user facing. Leave the spaces for the titles of people's word processing documents and spreadsheets.

Answer (score 5):

Use the `-f` argument to force removal.

```
docker rm -f $(docker ps -aq)
```

This will stop and remove the container in a single command. Adding `-v` will also remove anonymous volumes belonging to the container.

Comment: Thanks. Worth adding that `docker rm -f` sends a `SIGKILL` which abruptly terminates the running process, whereas `docker stop` allows it to shut down gracefully.

Comment: True, but if you intend to delete the container anyway that shouldn't matter much.

Comment: That depends on what the running processes are doing. If they send a message over the network to a host machine to say "I'm shutting down" then it does make a difference.

Answer (score 2):

Using history expansion:

```
docker stop $(docker ps -aq)
!:0 rm !:2*
```

or

```
docker stop $(docker ps -aq)
^stop^rm
```

Comment: Thanks, that's actually what I'm using at the moment, but seems a bit hacky as I either have to wait for the first command to finish, or type blindly while the first command spews its output. I was hoping for something succinct I can type on one line to do both commands.